# AutoMapper not mapping sub property

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I am receiving an issue with automapper v6.0.2 where automapper is trying to shove an `ICollection` into an `int` instead of the specified collection.

Error:

```
    Mapping types:
Member_B3B146AB4F61AEDE3DF3639BDBD65BFA5BCA0FC414F11960DC39DA834F2A8CBD -> ICollection`1
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Memberr_B3B146AB4F61AEDE3DF3639BDBD65BFA5BCA0FC414F11960DC39DA834F2A8CBD -> System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[MemberService.Dto.DependentDetailDto, MemberService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

Destination path:
MemberDetailDto.Dependents.Dependents

Source value:
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.MbmRosterSubscriber_B3B146AB4F61AEDE3DF3639BDBD65BFA5BCA0FC414F11960DC39DA834F2A8CBD ---> System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
```

Member

```
public Member ()
{
   this.Dependents = new HashSet<Dependent>();
}
public virtual ICollection<Dependent> Dependents { get; set; }
```

AutoMapper Config

```
CreateMap<Dependent, DependentDetailDto>();
CreateMap<Member, MemberDetailDto>()
                .ForMember(a => a.Dependents, o => o.MapFrom(x => Mapper.Map<ICollection<Dependent>, ICollection<DependentDetail>>(x.Dependents)));
```

Dependent:

```
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Dob { get; set; }
        public string Sex { get; set; }
        public string Relationship { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentCode { get; set; }
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public string Address3 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string MailCountry { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> SsnEncryptDate { get; set; }
```

When Dependents is removed Subscriber maps perfectly

As for the `Dependent` Entity and `Model` they are copy and paste with all items `public`. It appears as if AutoMapper is trying to squeeze the collection into an `int` instead of the specified map.

Any Ideas?

`Dependents` is a navigation property

Edit :
This was being tested in a functional test in an async method.
Quick unit test has been created:

```
[TestMethod]
public  void RetrieveActiveMember()
{
    MemberEntity.Member Subscriber = new Member();
    ICollection<Dependent> Dependent = new List<Dependent>();
    Dependent.Add(new Dependent { HostCountry = "HOME" });
    Subscriber.Dependents = Dependent;

    var Mapped = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Member, MemberDetailDto>(Subscriber);

    Assert.IsNotNull(Mapped);
}
```

Error being returned now is Method 'Add' in type X does not have an implementation'

```
Property:
Dependents ---> System.TypeLoadException: Method 'Add' in type 'Proxy<System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[MemberService.Dto.DependentDetailDto_MemberService_Version=1.0.0.0_Culture=neutral_PublicKeyToken=null]]_mscorlib_Version=4.0.0.0_Culture=neutral_PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089>' from assembly 'AutoMapper.Proxies, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005' does not have an implementation.
```

Changing The automapper config for the dependent to

```
CreateMap<ICollection<Dependent>, ICollection<DependentDetailDto>>()
                .ConstructUsing((ICollection<Dependent> Dependents) => {
                    List<DependentDetailDto> DependentList = new List<DependentDetailDto>();
                    foreach (var Dependent in Dependents)
                        DependentList.Add(new DependentDetailDto { });
                return DependentList;
            });
```

Makes the unit test work albeit no longer actually using Automapper which is a big caveat, however it still breaks on the functional test

I can't think of anything else to add as Dependents does not even have an integer field

Addendum: The entity, the Dto, and the caller are all in different libraries but I have not been able to replicate it in .NETFiddle

Comment: You forgot to add definition of `Dependent` and `DependentDetail` classes

Comment: Added, they are copy and paste with nothing left out except the class name declaration

Comment: Hmm still cannot reproduce your issue. Can you care a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not figure out the root cause of the issue, but found a fix.

Changed the `MemberDto` property `Dependents` name to `Dependentss` and it worked. Changing it back breaks it again. I should add there is no other Dependents property on either object.

I have no idea but the name appears to be what was breaking it.

Answer (score 2):

Automapper should normally handle collections for you. It will also look up any known maps that might apply, so no need to call `Mapper.Map` inside a `MapFrom`.

Just define the maps for individual entities:

```
CreateMap<Dependent, DependentDetailDto>();
CreateMap<Member, MemberDetailDto>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Dependents, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.Dependents);
```

Comment: This is good to know, however this did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Hm this works for me, however we initialize our collections with a `List<T>`. Please change `this.Dependents = new HashSet<Dependent>();` and see if this works.

Comment: No luck, it might be a DLL issue so I will have to play with it more and try to redo the references or namespaces again.

Comment: Does `HashSet<T>` have an implementation of the method `Add`? I think Automapper wants to add mapped dtos to the collection and can't...

Comment: IHashSet just contains an implementation of ICollection<T> that being said I have and can be used with the basic Add functions. That being said I have switched to List<T> just to double check also just tried switching to List for all the Icollections but no luck.